# Need help to search in base64 encoded MySQL field

Tags: mysql, base64

I am trying to find a string in a MySQL field which is encoded in base64 (for international characters)

Usual search:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%term%' ";
```

I have tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field name LIKE '%".base64_encode($term)."%'  ";
```

But it does not work all the time, depending on the search term length... For some reason, it gives result whenever my term is an odd-number long...

I have also tried using the MySQL function `TO_BASE64()` and `FROM_BASE64()` which did not work...

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compare the input value against the base64-decoded stored value, so reverse your attempt a little to call `FROM_BASE64()` on the stored value and compare against the plain input value. You cannot compare a partial match in `$term` if it is encoded because the partial value will never produce the same or even similar base64 string as the full stored value.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FROM_BASE64(`field`) LIKE '%$term%'
```

In this context, `$term` is a plain string, not base64 encoded. It's of course recommended that `$term` be a bound parameter rather than a plain PHP variable concatenated into the query.

However, **this is going to be *slow***.  If you are in any position to change the way your data has been stored, you are highly encouraged to store it in a plain unencoded form.  Every query will need to base64-decode *every* row to find a matching one, which is extremely inefficient.

Note also, that [`TO_BASE64(),FROM_BASE64()` were recently added in MySQL 5.6.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64), and therefore may not be available in a lot of installations. You really should change the way the data is stored to eliminate the encoding.

Comment: I'm getting this error message in PhpMyAdmin: #1305 - FUNCTION sameez.FROM_BASE64 does not exist ... so I guess this means I am not running the MySQL version needed?

Comment: That's correct. You can do plain equality tests `"WHERE column = '" . base64_encode($term) . "'"` to test that a full encoded input string matches, but there's really no way to do partial `LIKE` matches without access to the `FROM_BASE64()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to upgrade to MySQL 5.6 or above, you can use the following trick which is removing the padding issue:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE
field LIKE '%" . base64_encode($term) . "%' 
OR field LIKE '%" . substr(base64_encode($term .'a'),0,-4) . "%' 
OR field LIKE '%" . substr(base64_encode($term .'aa'),0,-8) . "%' 
OR field LIKE '%" . substr(base64_encode($term .'aaa'),0,-12) . "%'
```

The search term length issue is therefore avoided. You may optimize this query by using only one of the four `LIKE` depending on the length of the `$term`.