# Mysql 1305 function does not exist FROM_BASE64

Tags: mysql

MySQL query is as below:

```
Select count(*) From `zakaz` where  FROM_BASE64(`search_text`) like '%%'
```

as result I got an error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION myDB.FROM_BASE64 does not exist
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20956387/3164682

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 5.6.1

Comment: can I add this function manualy?

Answer (score 2):

FROM_BASE64() and T0_BASE64() functions are added in **Mysql 5.6.1** Version.
Check your mysql version before using these.

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)